# Why is this Insert XML into temp table so expensive?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have this simple XML which I need insert them into a temp table:

```
DECLARE
    @Handle INT,
    @Categories XML = 
N'<Categories>
  <Category ID="1000003950" />
  <Category ID="1000013931" />
  <Category ID="1000016715" />
  <Category ID="1000016713" />
</Categories>'

DECLARE @TempCategories TABLE (ID INT)

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @Handle OUTPUT, @Categories

INSERT INTO @TempCategories
SELECT A.* 
    FROM 
    (
     SELECT ID FROM 
     OPENXML(@Handle, '/Categories/Category', 2) 
      WITH (ID INT '@ID')
    ) A

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @Handle

SELECT * FROM @TempCategories
```

and I use the value in this temp table to perform some joins with some other tables to SELECT values.

It turn out that the most expensive operation is the above code, 83%!

[image: Expensive 83% query]

I do not understand why this is so?

Is there anyway to improve this query?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the overall duration of the query? Maybe 83% isn't that long, as write operations are a lot more expensive than reading values.

Comment: Don't go off these percentages. They are just estimates and in the case of XML based features often they are more or less just guesses.